# Working with repeates values in rows

Tags: r

I am working with a df of 46216 observation where the units are homes and people, where each home may have any number of integrants, like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGTXy.png)
and this for another almost 18000 homes.

What i need to do is to get the mean of education years for every home, for what i guess i will need a variable that computes the number of people of each home.

What i tried to do is:

`num_peopl=by(df$person_number, df$home, max)`, for each home I take the highest person number with the total number of people who live there, but when I try to cbind this with the df i get:

**"arguments imply differing number of rows: 46216, 17931"**

It is like it puts the number of persons only for one row, and leaves the others empty.

How can i do this? Is there a function?

Comment: I think you want a join.  Also, it would help if you provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I think aggregate and join may be what your looking for. Aggregate does the same thing that you did, but puts it into a data frame that I'm more familiar with at least.

Then I used dplyr left_join, joining the home number's together:

```
 library(tidyverse)
    df<-data.frame(home_number = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), 
person_number = c(1,2,3,1,2,1), 
age = c(20,21,1,54,50,30), 
sex = c("m","f","f","m","f","f"),
salary = c(1000,890,NA,900,500,1200), 
years_education = c(12,10,0,8,7,14))

    df2<-aggregate(df$person_number, by = list(df$home_number), max)

    df_final<-df%>%
      left_join(df2, by = c("home_number" = "Group.1"))

      home_number person_number age sex salary years_education x
    1           1             1  20   m   1000              12 3
    2           1             2  21   f    890              10 3
    3           1             3   1   f     NA               0 3
    4           2             1  54   m    900               8 2
    5           2             2  50   f    500               7 2
    6           3             1  30   f   1200              14 1
```